# How can I store characters of string variable in an integer array in Java

Tags: java, string, int

For example if:

```
String str = "100101010";
```

Then following should happen:

```
a[0]=1
a[1]=0
a[2]=0
...
```

It should hold for large strings also (up to 64 characters).

Comment: Can you narrow down which part of this problem you are struggling with?  This looks like a homework question, which the SO community will regularly boo off the stage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

One hint:  find a chart for ASCII. http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif The code for "0" is 48 and the code for "1" is 49.  You can convert characters to numbers just by subtracting 48 from the ASCII value.

```
int value = str.charAt(0) - 48;
```

It's important to realize that a Java `char` is just an integer type just like `int` and `byte`.  You can do math with them.  With that idea in mind, you should be able figure out the rest yourself.

(This is technically a duplicate since I answered a similar question long ago, but I can't find it, so you get a freebie.)

Comment: Or just `- '0'`, then you've not got the magic number in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int[] getAsArray(String value){
        // not null ;  not empty ;  contains only 0 and 1    
        if(value == null || value.trim().length()<1 || !value.matches("[0-1]+")){
            return new int[0];
        }
        //if it necessary !value.matches("[0-1]+" regex to validate 
        value = value.trim();
        value = value.length()>64 ? value.substring(0,63) : value;// up to 64 characters
        int[] valueAsInt = new int[value.trim().length()];
        for (int i = 0 ;i<value.length();i++){
            valueAsInt[i]=(int)value.toCharArray()[i]-48;
        }
        return valueAsInt;
    }
```

also if it's possible use shor or byte type as it's enoght to store 0,1 and you consume less memory as with int

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why you want to do this, but it is a simple problem.

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {

        String s = "111232";
        String element[] = s.split("");
        System.out.println(element[0]);
        System.out.println(element[1]);
        System.out.println(element[2]);
        System.out.println(element[3]);
        System.out.println(element[4]);
        System.out.println(element[5]);

    }
```